# ¿Por que me sale toda la tabla vacia con mysql?

Tags: mysql, sql

tengo que hacer lo siguiente :

Personas que nacieron antes del 2000 y ganan menos de 10000 y mas de 200000.

Lo que hice fue :

```
create database base1;
use base1;
create table Persona(

nombre varchar(50),

apellido varchar(50),

cuit varchar(50),

f_nacimiento date , 

ingreso_anual float ,

primary key(cuit));


insert into Persona(nombre , apellido , cuit , f_nacimiento , ingreso_anual)

 values
('89875212', 'Luz', 'Perez', '1996-01-25', 10000.0),

('12345678903', 'Camila', 'Guzman', '1993-09-10', 50000.0),

('12345678902' , 'Pepito' , 'Pepe'  , '1980-07-15' , 900000000.0),

('5698512' , 'Rosa' , 'Lopez'  , '2001-02-02' , 900.0),

('54345678904' , 'Lorenzo' , 'Williams'  , '1995-04-01' , 60000.5),

('78542' , 'Rocio' , 'Rodriguez'  , '1990-07-15' , 80000.0),

('5748542' , 'Carlos' , 'Vega'  , '1990-08-10' , 780140.0);

select *
from Persona
where (f_nacimiento <'2000-01-01') AND (ingreso_anual < 10000.0 AND ingreso_anual<200000.0);
```

pero cuando quiero ver la tabla me sale todo vacio y null , no se si estoy haciendo mal la consulta.

Comment: Creo que tu condición no está correcta, todos los que ganen más de 200000 ganan más de 10000, y en tu consulta buscas que ganen menos de 10000 y menos de 200000

Comment: menos de 10000 y mas de 200000??  y luego en la consulta buscas ingreso_anual < 10000.0 AND ingreso_anual<200000.0. creo que lo que buscas es que sea mayor a 10000 y menor de 200000 solo modifica ingreso_anual < 10000.0 por ingreso_anual > 10000.0

Comment: lo que busco es que el ingreso anual sea menor a 10000.0 y mayor a 200000.0 , cambie la condicion a : where (f_nacimiento <'2000-01-01') AND (ingreso_anual <10000.0 AND ingreso_anual>200000.0); pero me sigue tirando la tabla vacia con null @stre_leon

Comment: No hay datos que cumplan la condición que dices, con el ingreso menor a 10.000 hay un solo caso, Rosa Lopez con 900.0, pero su `f_nacimiento` no es menor a `2000-01-01`

Comment: Lo que pasa es que si quieres que sea menor a 10000 y mayor a 200000 es imposible... Simple lógica, un número no puede ser menor a 10000 y a su vez mayor a 200000.... sí lo que deseas es que te devuelva las tuplas que tengan un ingreso menor a 10000 ó mayor a 200000 entonces tienes que cambiar el AND por OR como te indican en una respuesta...

Answer (score 0):

No te devuelve datos por la siguiente condición que buscas que se cumpla:

```
(ingreso_anual < 10000.0 AND ingreso_anual<200000.0);
```

El operador `AND` busca que se cumpla tanto la condición de la izquierda como la de la derecha al mismo tiempo.

> Por lo que tu en teoría estas buscando que la columna `ingreso_anual` al mismo tiempo sea menor a 10000 y menor a 200000.

Considero que deberías

- Dejar solo 1 de las dos condiciones; es decir o solo los que ganan menos de 10000 o menos de 200000, considerando los de 10000 también serán traidos pidiendo los que ganen menos de 200000.

  (ingreso_anual < 200000)

Answer (score 0):

Tu problema esta en tu `where` actualmente el ingreso_anual indica de bebe ser siempre menor 10000 y como debería ser es estar entre el rango de 10000, 200000. solo tienes que cambiarlo ademas convierte tu fecha a tipo date

Ejemplo:

con `BETWEEN`

```
where f_nacimiento < CONVERT('2000-01-01',DATE)  AND ingreso_anual BETWEEN 10000.0 AND 200000.0;
```

ó

```
where f_nacimiento < CONVERT('2000-01-01',DATE) AND (ingreso_anual > 10000.0 AND ingreso_anual<200000.0);
```